# How to combine "and" statements and "if"statements in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, parentheses, and-operator

I am trying to write a check for Vendors and models in a form I have put together

Here is the relavent part of the form

```
<table  width="75%">
<form action="?" method="post">
<tr>
<td colspan="6" align="center">
<font size="5"><b>Add new record</b></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">
<b>Vendor:</b>
</td>
<td>
<select name="vendor">
<option value="ClearAccess">ClearAccess</option>
<option value="VisionNet">VisionNet</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
</td>
<td align="right">
<b>Model:</b>
</td>
<td>
<select name="model">
<option value="NotModel">--ClearAccess--</option>
<option value="AG10W">AG10W</option>
<option value="SR100G">SR100G</option>
<option value="SR300N">SR300N</option>
<option value="SR350N">SR350N</option>
<option value="SR500N">SR500N</option>
<option value="NotModel">--VisionNet--</option>
<option value="M404">M404</option>
<option value="M405">M405</option>
<option value="M505">M505</option>
<option value="M505n">M505N</option>
<option value="Legacy">Legacy</option>
</select>
</td>
```

my form is good.  my issue is when I am building my if loop.  Here is what I have so far

```
if ($_POST['vendor']='ClearAccess') && ($_POST['model']='M404') || ($_POST['model']='M405') || ($_POST['model']='M505') || (_$POST['model']='M505N') || ($_POST['model']='Legacy')
echo "You have not selected a valid vendor/model combination"
```

I am having an issue with where and how to place my parenthesis.

I am also going to create an if statement similar to this

```
if ($_POST['vendor']='VisionNet') && ($_POST['model']='AG10W') || ($_POST['model']='SR100G') || ($_POST['model']='SR300N') || (_$POST['model']='SR350N') || ($_POST['model']='SR500N')|| ($_POST['model']='Legacy')
echo "You have not selected a valid vendor/model combination"
```

I am completely open to doing it different ways.  Eventually I will turn this into java script where you pick a vendor and get only the relavant models for that vendor.  Put as I am still learning PHP and have not learned even the basics of Java yet I want to try it this way.

Comment: _"valid"_  should be _"invalid"_

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between `=` and `==`. `if ($_POST['vendor']='VisionNet')` will always return true because you are performing an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: @TimFountain in `if($_POST['vendor'] = 'VisionNet')` the close-parenthesis also ends the `if` statement

Comment: This might belong in [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Matt codereview's only for code that works.  This is far from working.

Comment: @SomeKittens a fair point, my friend.

Answer (score 4):

Reduce your logic. Start with what you want to do in general statements.

```
A = "Vendor is VisionNet"
B = "Model is AG10W"
C = "Model is SR100G"
etc.
```

Then write up your logic as

```
if (A and (B or C))
```

OR

```
if ((A and B) or C)
```

etc.

Then replace your place-holders with the PHP equivalent.

In PHP, if you're trying to see if x is one of many values, you can use the `in_array()` method:

```
$models = array('AG10W', 'SR100G', 'SR300N', 'SR350N', 'SR500N', 'Legacy');

// if the vendor is vision net OR the model is in the list of models defined in $models, do something
if ($_POST['vendor'] == 'VisionNet' || in_array($_POST['model'], $models)) {
    // do something.
}
```

Take [operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) into consideration as well. Assignment is different than comparison.

Remember, logic is just another subset of mathematics. Parentheses are important, so if you close your `if` statement early, that's the end of it. Everything after will become a syntax error.

I mention that because you wrote this:

```
if ($_POST['vendor'] = 'VisionNet') || ...
```

Here's a link to a tutorial on [discrete mathematics](http://math.about.com/od/discretemath/Discrete_Math.htm) which is a fancy way of saying "the mathematics of logic".

**Also, for all those interested, MIT (the Massachusetts Institute of Technology) offers open courses online for free, one of which is the [mathematics of computer science](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/) which discusses discrete math in-depth.**

Comment: Couldn't write better than this.

Comment: @Yazmat I tried making it as explicit as possible. The issue was not necessarily PHP, but a lack of knowledge about how logic works. OP needs a discrete mathematics course.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your problems :

1. Using `=` instead of `==`
2. Not placing `()` in the `if` statement

change from

```
if ($_POST['vendor']='ClearAccess') && ($_POST['model']='M404') || ($_POST['model']='M405') || ($_POST['model']='M505') || (_$POST['model']='M505N') || ($_POST['model']='Legacy')
```

to :

```
if (($_POST['vendor']=='ClearAccess') && ($_POST['model']=='M404') || ($_POST['model']=='M405') || ($_POST['model']=='M505') || (_$POST['model']=='M505N') || ($_POST['model']=='Legacy'))
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to use `===` instead of `=`.  The single equals means assignment, not comparing.

Secondly, what I think you're trying to do is say "if it's this vendor AND one of these models, do something.  If that's the case, try this:

```
   if($_POST['vendor'] === 'ClearAccess' && (*various models, using ||*))
       //dostuff
```

That way, it will equate to `true` if the vendor is equal as well as at least one of the models.

A better way to do this would be to build up an array of the various models and then use PHP's [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: It's a best practice.  `==` will do type conversion, which can cause weird errors.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis

Comment: @mlishn: Because some people don't like PHP's type juggling.  They contend that it's good practice to always use `===` unless you need PHP's type coercion magic (though they also like to think you *never* need it, and thus that you should never be using `==`).

Comment: @cHao so when using `===` do the two variables need to explicity defined with a variable type, or does PHP assume based on format? So something like `(string) $string="string";` vs. `$string="string";`

Comment: @mlishn: They don't have to be defined with a type; in PHP, the type is on the value, not the variable, and the type of a literal is pretty obvious.  But if two values are not the same type, `===` says they're never equal.  So if you expect them to be different types, you'd either cast them to the same type or use `==`.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `==` instead `=` in your if conditions.

So instead of:

```
if ($_POST['vendor']='ClearAccess') && ...
```

use

```
if ($_POST['vendor'] == 'ClearAccess') && ...
```

Better to have your if condition like this:

```
if ($_POST['vendor'] == 'ClearAccess') &&
    str_replace(array('M404', 'M405', 'M505', 'M505N', 'Legacy'), '', $_POST['model']) 
         != $_POST['model']
   )
   echo "You have not selected a valid vendor/model combination"
```

Comment: That's true, but the least of OP's problem.

Comment: @Matt: I dunno about "the least of OP's problem"; it's a pretty big reason for the failure.  The "conditions" would always return true, no matter what the original values were, because everything gets set to a truthy value (which gets returned as the value of that expression).  So even if the ||s and &&s and parentheses were right, the condition would still be very broken.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the php syntax for if then statements http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php because your syntax is wrong. You are assigning your post variables to values other than using ==

> if ($_POST['vendor']=='VisionNet')
>   Also, you should rethink your $$ and || usage and decide what that is actually saying in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your && within its own set of parenthesis. So the example below says if POST[vendor] is Clear Acces and POST[model] is M404, or POST[model] is M405, M505, M505N, or Legacy.

```
if (($_POST['vendor']=='ClearAccess') && ($_POST['model']=='M404')) || ($_POST['model']=='M405') || ($_POST['model']=='M505') || (_$POST['model']=='M505N') || ($_POST['model']=='Legacy') 
echo "You have not selected a valid vendor/model combination"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your ()'s right...

Just to make you aware of the syntax, here is the code with nice line breaks :)

```
if (
($_POST['vendor'] == 'ClearAccess' && $_POST['model'] = 'M404') || 
$_POST['model'] == 'M405' || 
$_POST['model'] == 'M505' || 
$_POST['model'] == 'M505N' ||
$_POST['model'] == 'Legacy'
) {
echo "You have not selected a valid vendor/model combination"
}
```

And without the linebreaks:

```
if (($_POST['vendor'] == 'ClearAccess' && $_POST['model'] == 'M404') || $_POST['model'] == 'M405' ||  $_POST['model'] == 'M505' || $_POST['model'] == 'M505N' || $_POST['model'] == 'Legacy') {
echo "You have not selected a valid vendor/model combination"
}
```

Your other statement goes the same way.